# Intuition behind why is unit speed parametrization and arc length parametrization the same?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition

I have found a bunch of simple and not so simple proofs about why a vector function ($f(t)$) parametrized in such a way that it's derivative is always 1 ($|f'(t)|=1$) is the same as parametrizing it by arc length ($f(s) \iff |f'(s)|=1$).

Just to provide one example of a proof found, I write down the definition for arclength with $t$ substituted with $s$
$$s=\int_0^s{|f(s)|}ds$$
apply derivative by both sides with respect to $s$
$$1=|f(s)|$$
BOOM!, proven.
(as long as the reparametrization is a biyective, smooth and has an inverse)

The question is, How can i understand this as an intuitive thing? I think im missing the "aha" moment where is makes sense that an arc length function would have unit speed.

Comment: If you reparametrize a path so that the length you are covering as you walk is equal to how you are counting time, then the scalar velocity will be $1$, since it is the limit of the length covered divided by time. Likewise, if the scalar velocity is $1$, then you are covering distance in the exact same way that time is passing by.

Comment: Unfortunately, the integral you wrote down makes no sense. You mean to write $s = \int_0^s g(t)\,dt$, say — integrating a function of $t$. Then it's true by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, assuming $g$ is *continuous*, that $1 = g(s)$ for every $s$.

Comment: If you walk at constant speed 1 during a time interval of length $T$ then the distance you walked is $T$.

Comment: @TedShifrin if $f(t)$ is parametrized in such a way that $s=t$ then would it not be the same to say $f(s)$?

Comment: No, if you write $\int_a^b f(s)\,dt$, then $s$ is a constant and the integral is $f(s)(b-a)$. The integral cannot read your mind.

Comment: oh i meant $ds$, not $dt$ there, i just edited it. thank you!

Comment: @Ned if you turn that into an answer I will accept it. makes perfect sense and it's as simple as it gets. <3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the question was about intuition ...

If you walk at a constant speed of $1$, then the distance you've covered in time $T$ is $T$.

Comment: This is the kind of intuition I like, it even makes the question look silly.

Answer (score 4):

I think the intuitive argument that I would use here is to think of the curve $f$ as taking a real interval $(a,b)$ to some curve segment $f((a,b))$ in a manifold or Euclidean space.  Having $||f'(s)|| = 1$ for all $s$ is kind of like saying that "$f$ traces out the curve segment just as quickly as it passes through values in $(a,b)$".

Imagine if $||f'(s)|| >1$, then the curve segment would get traced out quicker than the interval $(a,b)$ meaning that the curve segment would have a length shorter than $b-a$.  Similarly, if $||f'(s)|| < 1$ it would take a longer interval $(a,b+\epsilon)$ to trace out the curve hence the segment would have a length longer than $b-a$.